# Split a large css file or not?

Tags: css

My css file is very large and not suitable for maintenance. I decided to split it into 5 smaller ones and then import them all into one main.css, like this:

```
@import url('menutop.css');
@import url('wraptop.css');
@import url('body.css');
...
```

Will entire site become slower or not?
Is there any other downside of this approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A potential downside is that the browser must make multiple HTTP calls to the server before it can know the styles to use.

In general, CSS minification is a good strategy. In fact, many sites split the CSS during development then bundle the files together and minify them into one blob.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a chance to make your site slow. You can compress your css if they are too large. There are different online minifier are avilalble,you can try one of them. For example, i often compress my css from here https://cssminifier.com/

Answer (score 1):

If is too large firstly try to minify (compress) CSS with online tools. Check out for "css minifier", etc.